# Excel VLOOKUP #N/A

Tags: excel, vlookup

What I am trying to achieve is matching two projects with eachother "Project No" in two tables, and return the "project name" in second table. When I do this I receive this error inside the cell error #N/A.

I have formated both tables into number value, but this does not solve the problem.

Anyone that has an idea what I can do in order to solve this problem.

Here is the first table (just a snapshot to give an idea).

[image]

Here is the second table (just a snapshot to give an idea).

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the formula you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #N/A error indicates that Excel cannot find the value you've specified in the list in which you've told it look.  When I run into this, there are a few things I do to troubleshoot:

**1) Make sure both columns are in the same format.**

You mention you've already done this (good job!) but sometimes formatting gets stuck in Excel.  One thing you can do is to highlight each range and use the text to columns feature (under the data tab) to convert it all to the same format.  Another option is to copy the range into Notepad or some other plain text editor and then copy it back into Excel to strip out any lingering formatting.

**2) Double check your ranges.**

Make sure your Vlookup is looking to the correct range, and make sure that range is locked (i.e. $A$1:$D$100 rather than A1:D100), or else your ranges are going to slide around as you move drag the formula down your table.  If the range refers explicitly to a table address (e.g. Table1[#All]), then make sure every data point if validly within that table.

**3) Make sure the range lookup parameter is set to FALSE**

Range lookup is the last parameter of the vlookup, and determines whether the vlookup will find an exact match (set range lookup to FALSE) or a partial match (set range lookup to TRUE).  Setting range lookup to TRUE can sometimes create errors like the one you've described. I always set it to FALSE by default unless I need specifically need to set it to TRUE.

**4) Use the find and replace window to manually evaluate the formula**

If everything looks correct, copy the value you want to look up and paste it into the find and replace window to search for it.  If Excel can't find it and you can see it in your list, something is definitely wrong with the formatting or else your file may have some degree of corruption.  If Excel can find the value, double check that it is within the range your vlookup is looking through.

Answer (score 0):

If fist table is the one with vlookup formula and second is a source it may mean that such Project No. doesn't exist in your source table. Did you check that possibility?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and the table consists of that data.